# How can retrieve chain of certificates via openssl

Tags: openssl

I have to retrieve and download on my local environment certificate chain from remore server.
I can do it using browser embedded services, but as far as I know this approach does not work for chain of certificates (or have some bottlenecks). That's why I am trying to use openssl following command:

`openssl s_client -showcerts -connect host.host:9999`

which will print out appropriate cert info like:

```
CONNECTED(0000015C)
depth=1 /C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=google.com
   i:/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIcFzCCG4CgAwIBAgIGR09PUAFxMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAMEYxCzAJBgNVBAYT
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 1 s:/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority
   i:/C=US/O=Equifax/OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIICsDCCAhmgAwIBAgIDC2dxMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAME4xCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVT
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=google.com
issuer=/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 8040 bytes and written 310 bytes
```

How can I get this in .crt or .cer format? Can I just copy/paste this in text file with appropriate extension? If yes, where is the start and end of chain?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what exactly you mean by '.crt' or '.cer' format. If you copy those pieces of output between **-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----** and **-----END CERTIFICATE-----** and save them to a text file you will get a certificate chain file in PEM format (default for openssl). Your file should look something like this (2 certificates in the chain):

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIF/DCCBWWgAwIBAgIKUCYyawAAAAB1rzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBGMQswCQYD
<the rest of the certificate 1>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIICsDCCAhmgAwIBAgIDC2dxMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAME4xCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVT
<the rest of the certificate 2>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: I searched for some specific command to retrieve file with appropriate  chains with out copy-paste from command line.  I foung solution - use regular windows output. openssl s_client -showcerts -connect host.host:9999 >> tomcat.crt

Comment: *"I have no idea what exactly you means by '.crt' or '.cer' format"* - you have to read between the lines because there's not much in the way of naming standards. Often, that means the certificate is ASN.1/DER encoded. But sometimes they are PEM encoded, too. I usually use '.pem' for PEM, but I've seen some CAs publish their certificates in PEM and use '.crt' or '.cer' format.

Comment: FYI:  I've been putting all of my certificates in separate .pem files in the ```Java/Sun-JRE/*/customcerts``` directory.  I just now tried combining them into one certificate chain file as described above, and my app doesn't like it at all.  YMMV